# Program/tool for reading/logging http requests and responses?

Tags: json, http, gmail

I'm trying to log autocomplete responses from a gmail "people" server, and I'm trying to find a program or tool to do this, like the network section in chrome dev tools. I tried using a web crawler script, but authentication would be a mess. I also tried Wireshark, but it was all garble to me and probably the wrong way to go. Is this even possible? Can somebody help me, I'm totally out of my comfort zone here. 
 *[please see attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btQKu.png)*

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to find an API that google makes public for the data that you need and use that to query the data. For people, google does have an API. Have a look here: https://developers.google.com/people

Tools commonly used to make HTTP queries are https://www.postman.com/ and https://curl.haxx.se/